# Limit the size of a directory by deleting old files

Tags: bash, scripts, directory, resource-limiting

I have a IP cam which save its recordings in a specific directory named **Camera1** in my **Ubuntu Server 12.04**.

I would like to limit the size of this folder to **5 gigs**, by deleting -say once a day- the oldest files.

I first checked the **quota** program but it doesn't seem to allow the creation of new files and deleting of the old ones.

So I think the best method would be to run a bash script...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `find` command can be used to find files and delete them. The following command, for example, will delete files created more than seven days ago:

```
find /path/Camera1 -ctime +7 -delete
```

Use `crontab` if you want to schedule it; there is [more information here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. It doesn't fit exactly my needs but it's light and will do the trick 99% anyway!

Comment: BE CAREFUL, THIS will delete your hidden files as well

Answer (score 10):

I was in a very similar situation. I have a big LVM partition holding 2 directories:

- Videos (live streams recorded) can use 88% of the partition
- Pictures (pictures sent by the cameras when detecting motion) can use 7% of the partition (as pictures are much lighter, I can still keep older pictures than videos)

The remaining 5% is a security margin so that the partition never gets full. Note I am talking in percentages instead of fixed gigabytes because the size of my LVM partition changes if I replace or add a hard drive.

So here is the script (I added many comments so it's easily understandable):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
#Usage = sh limit-directory-size.sh /media/computer/mypartition 88 120 ("/media/computer/mypartition" = the directory to be limited / "88"=the percentage of the total partition this directory is allowed to use / "120"=the number of files to be deleted every time the script loops (while $Directory_Percentage > $Max_Directory_Percentage)

#Directory to limit
Watched_Directory=$1
echo "Directory to limit="$Watched_Directory

#Percentage of partition this directory is allowed to use
Max_Directory_Percentage=$2
echo "Percentage of partition this directory is allowed to use="$Max_Directory_Percentage

#Current size of this directory
Directory_Size=$( du -sk "$Watched_Directory" | cut -f1 )
echo "Current size of this directory="$Directory_Size

#Total space of the partition = Used+Available
Disk_Size=$(( $(df $Watched_Directory | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $3}')+$(df $Watched_Directory | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $4}') ))       
echo "Total space of the partition="$Disk_Size

#Curent percentage used by the directory
Directory_Percentage=$(echo "scale=2;100*$Directory_Size/$Disk_Size+0.5" | bc | awk '{printf("%d\n",$1 + 0.5)}')
echo "Curent percentage used by the directory="$Directory_Percentage

#number of files to be deleted every time the script loops (can be set to "1" if you want to be very accurate but the script is slower)
Number_Files_Deleted_Each_Loop=$3
echo "number of files to be deleted every time the script loops="$Number_Files_Deleted_Each_Loop

#While the current percentage is higher than allowed percentage, we delete the oldest files
while [ $Directory_Percentage -gt $Max_Directory_Percentage ] ; do
    #we delete the files
    find $Watched_Directory -type f -printf "%T@ %p\n" | sort -nr | tail -$Number_Files_Deleted_Each_Loop | cut -d' ' -f 2- | xargs rm
    #we delete the empty directories
    find $Watched_Directory -type d -empty -delete
    #we re-calculate $Directory_Percentage
    Directory_Size=$( du -sk "$Watched_Directory" | cut -f1 )
    Directory_Percentage=$(echo "scale=2;100*$Directory_Size/$Disk_Size+0.5" | bc | awk '{printf("%d\n",$1 + 0.5)}')
done
```

Then you call it every 15 minutes with a crontab entry

```
*/15 * * * * sh /home/computer/limit-directory-size.sh /media/computer/mypartition/videos 88 120
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Shouldn't you recalculate Directory_Percentage on the while loop?

Comment: @Luis Lobo Borobia, you are right! I just updated the script with the correction

Comment: I suspect you are using motion as I am. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

I started thinking about how hard it would be to only keep a certain amount of files. I turned to awk, which I have not used for a while, and came up with the following one liner.

```
cd /path/to/Camera1 && ls -ltc | awk '{ if (!system("test -f " $9)) { size += $5; if (size > 5*2^30 ) system("rm " $9) } }'
```

1. change to directory in question
2. list files, newest first
3. Run awk on output, check that it is a regular file, add file size to counter, remove file if cumulative size over 5 gigs

You can change "rm " to "ls " to have it list the files it would remove. It would be insane not to carefully test a script, suggested by an unknown on the net, which removes files!

The script will probably break and/or not do what you expect if you have funny characters (space for example) in the filenames.

Answer (score 3):

You could write a little bash script that just has a [find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) command like

```
find /Camera1 -atime +7 -exec rm {} \;
```

This would remove all files that haven't been accessed in over 7 days from the folder /Camera1.
Obviously this isn't quite what you wanted, but I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Excellent solution with awk!

I would however take an additional step to stop your trashcan overflowing.

In my cron..

wipes old cam shots if over 500mb (please notice the fix of size += $5)

```
*/2 * * * * cd /home/me/Desktop/Dropbox/a_security_cam && ls -ltc | awk '{ if (!system("test -f " $9)) { size += $5; if (size > 0.5*2^30 ) system("rm " $9) } }'
```

empties trash oldest first over 2gb

```
*/10 * * * * autotrash –min-free 2048
```

See http://www.logfish.net/pr/autotrash/