# How to delete files and subdirectories by size and age?

Tags: scripts, delete

I have a ubuntu server 12.10 which receives images from a camera by FTP, I receive the images in a directory with a fixed quote on the server and I need to delete the oldest images first, I would like to keep 1Gb free for new images.

I have followed [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176480/limit-the-size-of-a-directory-by-deleting-old-files) but cannot find the solution there.

`autotrash` would be a good command but I do not have gnome installed.

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: The question you linked has plenty of good solutions for this problem. Can you detail which one you tried and why it didn't work for you? If it's a server, a crontab entry would be the best. If you know the image reception schedule the easiest way is to delete all files older than X days, if you have images of approximately the same size coming in at regular intervals you can easily figure out the needed "age" so that you have about 1 GB free at all times.

Answer (score 0):

Your original question is "How to delete files and subdirectories by size and age". Use find:

This will delete all files under the current directory larger than 2 MB:

```
find ./ -size +2M -delete
```

This will delete all files created more than 7 days ago:

```
find ./ -ctime +7 -delete
```