# Rotate binary files

Tags: bash, logrotate

I'm trying to solve a problem with rotating binary files.

I have video files which are recorded from IP camera, and I want to delete oldest files when I have less then e.g. 10 Gb of free space.

Files are named in `%Y%m%d%H%M%S.h264` format, for example `20150624123600.h264`.

First I was thinking of using `logrotate` for that, but with config

```
/data/video/.h264 {
    rotate 20
    nocompress
    dateext
    dateformat %Y%m%d%H%M%S
    extension .h264
    missingok
}
```

I get message `log /data/video/.h264 does not exist -- skipping` while files like `/data/video/20150624123600.h264` are exist. I also tried to add prefix, but it didn't help.

Could you help me with solving this problem - deleting oldest files (according to the date in file name) when free space limit is reached?
It could be just bash script or logrotate config, or anything that could be run on ubuntu server.

Comment: Just use `/data/video/*.h264`to solve your initial problem..regarding your new question, after how many rotations the file will be deleted ? also note that AFAIK its not possible to take any decision based on the free space of the computer in `logrotate` although you can use `size` parameter of `logrotate` to rotate files greater than a certain size..

Answer (score -1):

You find a very detailed answer here in the second reply.

[Limit the size of a directory by deleting old files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176480/limit-the-size-of-a-directory-by-deleting-old-files)

to access cron you should type

```
crontab -e
```

Comment: This is not a direct answer to the question..

Comment: @heemayl and how much effort does it take to solve it from that script?